# Как сделать/настроить WCF-сервис, чтобы он постоянно слушал определенный порт?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, клиент-сервер

Мне поставили задачу сделать WCF-сервис, который будет слушать определенный порт и делать определенные действия. Т.е., как я понимаю, **сам сервис постоянно работает, и постоянно слушает опр. порт**. Ранее я делал сервисы, которые просто отвечают на запрос клиента и не понимаю, в чем разница - как сделать/настроить сервис, чтобы он постоянно был включенным?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении мне двигаться.

**UPD**

Нужно ли єто как-то особенно настраивать сервис в ИИСе, или можно просто использовать бесконечный цикл во время работы слушающего сокета?

Comment: Нет никакой разницы. Сервисы, которые вы делали, отвечали на запрос клиента. Делали это они за счет того, что постоянно слушали определенный порт, и реагировали на приходящий на этот порт запрос. Вам стоит спросить в чем же разница у того, кто поставил задачу.

Comment: @PashaPash, в моих пред. сервисах, сервис грубо говоря возвращал какой-то ответ. Я нигде там не прописывал слушать адресс/порт. В этом же случае, я не совсем понимаю, как запустить его, чтобы он постоянно работал. Он буде выложен на ИИС на сервере

Comment: запрос же он от клиента получал? по сети? или вы делали не-WCF сервисы, а просто какие-то классы писали?

Comment: @PashaPash, да, конечно -по сети. То были WCF сервисы

Comment: ну раз они получали запросы по сети - значит они слушали какой-то порт. или 80-й (если работали под IIS) или какой-то другой - если работали не под IIS

Comment: потому что единственный способ получить запрос по сети - слушать порт (прямо или косвенно)

Comment: 1: а, понятно. Т.е. чтобы сервис постоянно работал, он должен быть запущен в ИИС, и он вертится постоянно?

Comment: 2: чтобы сервис слуша адресс/порт, нужно в бесконечном цикле  использовать принимающий сокет, и дело в шляпе?

Comment: 2 - не совсем так. там есть готовый класс, который умеет хостить сервис в чем угодно. это все подробно расписано в [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms730158(v=vs.110).aspx), тянуть все копипастой не получится. если будет время - попробую оформит как краткий ответ

Comment: @PashaPash, надеюсь у Вас будет время, я честно говоря не понимаю смысл вашего комментария(

Comment: почитайте статью https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms730158(v=vs.110).aspx - это полноценный ответ. просто он слишком большой для быстрой копипасты сюда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Сервис может работать как служба Windows или как консольное приложение.
2. WCF-сервис и так слушает порт.
3. Можно сделать свой `WebHttpDispatchOperationSelector` для перенаправления всех запросов на один метод. Ну или набор методов, которые тебе нужны.
4. Объявление аргумента метода с типом `Stream` позволяет принимать любые данные.
   Аналогично с возвращаемым значением.
5. Кстати, можно настроить binding с использованием любого протокола, не только http.

PS: А вообще, что-то WCF-сервис не кажется тут логичным выбором.